# Append an element before a element wrapping a body innerHTML, vanilla Js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert an element before an element wrapping over the body but getting the following

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

```
document.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML = '<div id="boat">' + document.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML  + '</div>';

var sailor = document.createElement( 'aside' );
sailor.setAttribute( 'id', 'sailor' );
sailor.parentNode.insertBefore( document.getElementById( 'boat' ), sailor );
```

Any ideas on how to realize the following structure?

```
<body>
  <aside id="sailor"></aside>
  <div id="boat">
    <!-- 
    rest of the content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sailor` node has no parent, it is the `boat` element you have to ge the parent of. Also, the node you are inserting is the first parameter.

```
var sailor = document.createElement( 'aside' );
sailor.setAttribute( 'id', 'sailor' );
var boat = document.getElementById( 'boat' );
boat.parentNode.insertBefore( sailor, boat );
```

Comment: Perfect, on point. Hard to switch back from jQ to jS.

Answer (score 0):

sailor is not added into the DOM so it doesn't have a parent.. you need to add it into the DOM first before you can access its parent element

Answer (score 0):

`sailor.parentNode.insertBefore( document.getElementById( 'boat' ), sailor );`

Here you're trying to get the parent node of an element that does not exist on the DOM, so there is no parent hence null.

Also that isn't the correct way to use the `insertBefore` method. From the MDN web documentation I see

`let insertedNode = parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`

The div with id boat is the reference node, the sailor element is the new node and the body is the parent node. With that we can rewrite the code as

```
document.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML = '<div id="boat">' + document.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML  + 'test </div>';

var sailor = document.createElement( 'aside' );
console.log(sailor);
sailor.setAttribute( 'id', 'sailor' );
document.body.insertBefore( sailor, document.getElementById( 'boat' ) )
```